# How many possible ways of counting to 100 using only a collection of certain number

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

SEE EDIT BELOW: Lets say that I have the set {$ 2,3,4,5,6,7 $} and that I want to add multiples $\geq0$ of these elements in different orders (sequences) to get $100$. How many such sequences are there?

At first I thought about the number of non-negative integer solutions to an equation on this form:
$$x_1\ +\ x_2\ +\ ...\ +\ x_n\ =\ k$$
but doesn´t that just count the number of times each element occurs? Can I use this, and if so, how, and then somehow order them and count the number of sequences? How can I do this?

---

EDIT: Im sorry for the confusion but I need to correct some things, my bad. The goal is to partition the number $100$ into EXACTLY $15$ integers-parts where all these parts must be multiples of elements of the set {$2,3,4,5,6,7$}. I know that the number of partitions of $100$ into exactly $15$ parts is $p(100,15)$, but these include all the partitions using all the numbers from $1$ to $100$, right?

So is there a way to just get the partitions of the set above? Thank you for great answers so far even though I messed the question up!

Comment: You need the number of positive integral solutions of $2x_1+3x_2+...+7x_6=100$. Denote the number of solutions of $a_1x_1+...a_nx_n=k$ by $N(a_1,...,a_n;k)$. Then you have recurrent relations like $\sum_{l=1}^{\lfloor k/a_1\rfloor} N(a_2,...,a_n, k-la_1)=N(a_1,...,a_n,k)$. You solve it by considering a generation function.

Comment: @cittee To make I understand what you are trying to count: if the target were $8$ instead of $100$, would the complete list of valid sequences be
$$
[6,2],[2,6],[3,5],[5,3],[4,4],[3,3,2],[3,2,3],[2,3,3],[2,2,2,2]\quad ?
$$

Comment: OEIS: [A013984](http://oeis.org/A013984)

Comment: @MikeEarnest also $[4,2,2],[2,4,2],[2,2,4]$

Comment: @MikeEarnest, yes that would be correct without the constraints I forgot to add to the question. I have now added that in the EDIT. Each partition should consist of exactly 15 elements, and one must use the elements in the set I wrote above. So what you did here is the right idea but ONLY those sequences consisting of exactly the right number of elements. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Based on your response to @MikeEarnest, you're interested in counting certain integer compositions rather than integer partitions.  In partitions, the order of the summands doesn't matter, so there are 5 partitions of 4 = 3+1 = 2+2 = 2+1+1 = 1+1+1+1.  But there are 8 compositions of 4 (add in 1+3, 1+2+1, and 1+1+2).

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n$ be the number of sequences that add up to $n$.  Then $a_n=0$ for $n<0$, and $a_0=1$.  Conditioning on the first element of the sequence yields recurrence
$$a_n = \sum_{i=2}^7 a_{n-i},$$
which you can readily use to compute $a_{100}$.

---

To obtain the generating function $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, multiply both sides of the recurrence by $z^n$ and add them up, yielding
\begin{align}
A(z) 
&= a_0 z^0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=2}^7 a_{n-i} z^n \\
&= 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=2}^{\min(7,n)} a_{n-i} z^n \\
&= 1+\sum_{i=2}^7 \sum_{n=i}^\infty a_{n-i} z^n \\
&= 1+\sum_{i=2}^7 z^i \sum_{n=i}^\infty a_{n-i} z^{n-i} \\
&= 1+\sum_{i=2}^7 z^i A(z) \\
&= 1+A(z) \frac{z^2-z^8}{1-z},
\end{align}
so
$$A(z) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2-z^8}{1-z}} = \frac{1-z}{1-z-z^2+z^8}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I overlooked that.  I therefore deleted my answer.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out after I commented, and then deleted my comment.  Your answer is very elegant. +1.

Comment: Thank you for the response! What if my sequence has to consist of exactly $m$ positive integers (using the same set)?

Comment: Please open a separate question for that.

Comment: @RobPratt Would that be better than just editing? I could absolutely do that if it is, I just messed up the question a bit because I missed important points and wanted to correct it. All the answers are great even though they are not exactly what I search for in this particular case. My bad for not being clear

Comment: It is a different question, and you already have answers and comments for the original question.  Better to ask separately.